# Providing a definition for a pure-virtual function

Tags: c++, virtual

I'm a Java programmer and was confued about the fact of providing the defintion for pure-virtual functions. In Java I'm used to think about abstract methods as methods we'll provide the deifinitions in a base class. But the following code is perfectly valid:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
   virtual ~A() = 0;
};

A::~A(){ std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl; }

struct B : A
{
    ~B(){ std::cout << "~B()" << std::endl; }
};

A *a = new B;


int main()
{
    delete a;
}
```

But if we try to do something like that:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
   virtual ~A() = 0;
   virtual void foo() = 0;
};

void A::foo(){ }
A::~A(){ std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl; }

struct B : A
{
    ~B(){ std::cout << "~B()" << std::endl; }
};

A *a = new B;


int main()
{
    delete a;
}
```

The compiler's going to complaing about providing no definition for pure virtual functions. Why can we define the pure-virtual destructor in a namesapace scope, but can't do that for usual member function.

Is that rather an exception than a rule?

Comment: What? Providing a definition for a pure virtual function is perfectly legal. The compiler will never complain about that. The only problem with your second code is that you are trying to instantiate abstract class `B`, not with providing a definitiot for a pure function.

Comment: @AnT But I did that within the namespace scope. I provided that definition, what's wrong?

Comment: Where? I don't see a definition for `B::foo` anywhere. `A::foo` is a pure virtual function. Unless you override it with `B::foo`, it will remain pure in `B` as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are allowed to define any pure virtual member function. However, even though you define `A::foo`, it is still pure, so `A` and `B` are still abstract classes and may not be instantiated. That will be the cause of any errors your compiler may emit.

Comment: So, the class stop being abstract iff we override its pure virtual functions? But in the destructor case we didn't do that, we only provided a definition for the virtual destructor.

Comment: @St.Antario: Yes, the class stops being abstract when you override all of its virtual functions with non-pure functions. What exactly does your "we didn't do that" mean? Yes, we did do that. When you wrote the non-pure destructor in `B`, you *overrode* the pure destructor of `A`. Even though the destructor names are different, destructors still always override each other. They are special in that regard.

Comment: @St.Antario Yes, if in class `B` you declare all its member functions to be non-pure and override all pure member functions inherited from base classes, then `B` won't be abstract. Note that for the destructor this happens automatically when you don't declare it yourself.

Comment: I got that. The key thing was 10.3/6 __Even though destructors are not inherited, a destructor in a derived class overrides a base class destructor
declared virtual;__

Answer (score 2):

You are apparently confused about the reason for the error in the second version of the code.

There's nothing wrong with providing a definition for a pure virtual function, any pure virtual function, in namespace scope. It doesn't matter whether it is a destructor or a regular function. No compiler will ever complain about that.

The definition for `A::foo` you provided in the second version of the code is perfectly legal and causes no complaints from the compiler. The only problem with your second code is that `B` does not override `foo`. Hence `B` is still an abstract class. And you are attempting to instantiate it.

In the first version of the code the only pure function `B` inherited from `A` was the destructor, and a non-pure definition for the destructor was provided in `B`. So, `B` was is no longer abstract class and can be legally instantiated.

In the second version of the code `B` inherits two pure virtual functions from `A` - the destructor and `foo`. Since you did not override `foo` in `B`, `B` is still an abstract class and cannot be instantiated.

That's all there is to it. The error has nothing to do with the ability to provide a body for a pure virtual function in namespace scope.

Comment: Wait, I provided the definition for the virtual member function, therefore A nd B are no loger abstract.

Comment: @St.Antario: No. Providing a body for a pure virtual function does not "unpure" that function. The function remains pure and class remains abstract. Class `A` is abstract in both versions of the code. Class `B` is abstract in the second version of the code.

Answer (score 1):

When I compile the above program using g++ 4.8.2, I get the following messages:

Compiler command:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11     socc.cc   -o socc
```

Error messages:

```
socc.cc:17:12: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘B’
 A *a = new B;
            ^
socc.cc:12:8: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘B’:
 struct B : A
        ^
socc.cc:9:6: note:  virtual void A::foo()
 void A::foo(){ }
      ^
make: *** [socc] Error 1
```

The gist of the error message is that `B` is an abstract type since it doesn't provide an overriding `void foo();`, which is declared as a pure virtual function in the base class.

The definition of `A::foo()` is not illegal. The following program works just fine:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
   virtual ~A() = 0;
   virtual void foo() = 0;
};

void A::foo(){ }
A::~A(){ std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl; }

struct B : A
{
    ~B(){ std::cout << "~B()" << std::endl; }
     void foo() {}  // Need this to be able to instantiate B.
};

A *a = new B;

int main()
{
    delete a;
}
```